# Search for a matching string through more then one files in Java

Tags: java, file

I am attmpting to search through more then one text files in java for a matching random string ( given from the user ). I got myself a loop which loops throug filenames in the current directory in the project but i can't figure out how to open the files and check if i have a match somewhere int them. Here is the code that i have written to loop through the filenames.

```
String path = ".";  //current directory 
    java.io.File folder = new java.io.File( path );
    java.io.File[] fileList = folder.listFiles();
    for( int i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++ ) {
    // I should add code for searching int the files probably here 
    }
```

My research got me to some code for searching matches but in only one file and it looks like this:

```
final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(FileName); 
    while (scanner.hasNextLine())  {
       final String lineFromFile = scanner.nextLine(); 
       if(lineFromFile.contains("Address"))  { 
           // a match!
           System.out.println("I found " + CurrClient.getClientName() 
                         + " in file " +FileName+"txt");
           break;
       }
    }
```

But it works only with one file or it seems to me like this.

Can you please give me a push? :)

Comment: You have (1) a list of files and (2) a function that accepts a single file name and scans that file. .. What more do you *think* you need?

Comment: beside you are working with files, you need [thread](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/06/java-threading.html) in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `FileName` with `fileList[i]` and your should be on your way.

By the way, you must remember to close the scanner in the end of each iteration of the loop, by calling `scanner.close()`. See more [the examples in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)